# How to keep separate database for each organisation in my NodeJs app with MongoDb?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am building a management application for NGOs based on NodeJs & MongoDB(mongoose ODM). 
I am required to keep a separate DB for each NGO, and when users from a particular NGO login, they will get access to data from their NGO's database automatically.

Applications should able to connect users to their respective databases(NGO) as soon as they log in.

They are so many questions that I am unable to answer:

1. Should I first create databases then create users and link them with respective databases?
2. How would the application connect users to their DB during login?

I need to know if there's a popular way of handling such a case. I am fairly new to NodeJs, any help and guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Note: *It's important for the project to have separate DB for each NGO*

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB creates databases as needed automatically, depending on operations performed, so creating databases manually may not be necessary. (Although if you, for example, specifically list databases, then you'd only get back the databases that were used/already created.)

The users themselves, and which databases they are associated with, you'd store in a different database, ensuring that it is absolutely impossible for any of these users to access the user database.